# Electron/Chrome CSP issue

Tags: google-chrome, electron, content-security-policy

given I have

```js
const {app,  BrowserWindow, session } = require('electron');

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: {
        ...details.responseHeaders,
        // 'Content-Security-Policy': ['script-src \'unsafe-inline\' \'self\';'],
        'Content-Security-Policy': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOW-FROM *'
      }
    });
  });

  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
      sandbox: false,
      webSecurity: false,
      webviewTag: true
    }
  });

  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
      const childWindow = window.open('https://example.com');
      childWindow.addEventListener('message', console.log);
    `);
  });
  await win.loadFile('main.html');

  win.webContents.openDevTools({mode: 'detach', activate: true});
});
```

I am getting

```
VM172:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "file://" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at \<anonymous\>:1:13
(anonymous) @ VM172:1
```

How to disable it completely or set it up properly?

a lot (too much). Spent long hours to check different configuration and nothing works